# Download Stack Overflow database

Tags: discussion, data-dump

I recently attended a conference where the speaker referenced the Stack Overflow database and actually did queries against it.

Some of the queries that he has provided to us also use the Stack Overflow database.  I have looked in this forum and in the DBA forum to find it, to download it, so that I (and the others at the seminar) can actually *use* the queries, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for? https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Comment: @AaronLS - This may actually be where I need to be, but I understood that we could download the db to actually put stressors on our servers for testing.  I will try using this, thanks!  -- No, didn't work - I am not permitted to CRATE PROCEDURE (probably a good thing!)

Comment: @Deb You can create queries on the currently actual data as mentioned, why you wan't to download a copy of SO's database?

Comment: @Deb [See this on Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

Comment: "I am not permitted to CRATE PROCEDURE (probably a good thing!)" -- Truer words have never been spoken. (*CREATE PROCEDURE)

Comment: @GEOCHET - LOL - you are sooo right!

Answer (score 28):

There is no need to download the database.

Just use the online tools: https://data.stackexchange.com/

If you really have your heart set on downloading actual data, you can get data dumps here: https://archive.org/details/stackexchange

Comment: It's actually surprisingly small, at just 7gb for Stack Overflow (compressed).

Comment: why there are differences between these 2?  In https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new database has 27 tables, while in archive.org/details/stackexchange, databse has 8 tabes?

Comment: Why not ask that as a question, instead of leaving it as a comment?

Answer (score 26):

Brent Ozar here - I might have been the speaker because I do a lot of demos with the Stack Overflow databases running on Microsoft SQL Server.

If you want to follow along with the demos in SQL Server, I keep a [torrent of the SQL Server version of the data dump here](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/10/how-to-download-the-stack-overflow-database-via-bittorrent/).

Comment: Real nice! :) I'm sure going to use this in my master's degree dissertation. Brent, do you know any area\topics that I could explore during my research? I mean, a topic related to information search and retrieval or something like that I could use the database to play with...

Comment: Leniel - no, but you could start with http://data.stackexchange.com, which is a repository of queries people have run against the database.

Comment: Yes, you were the speaker :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can use Google BigQuery to query the quarterly dumps too.

Announcement:

- https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-bigquery-public-datasets-now-include-stack-overflow-q-a-5a8a7e371b52

For example, here I share how to calculate the average response time for any query:

- [BigQuery SQL: Average, geometric mean, remove outliers, median](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51981353/bigquery-sql-average-geometric-mean-remove-outliers-median)

Or the number of pageviews per quarter per tag (not an easy task anywhere else):

- https://towardsdatascience.com/these-are-the-real-stack-overflow-trends-use-the-pageviews-c439903cd1a