# How can one save Stack Overflow posts to Evernote?

Tags: feature-request

Well, I wanted to save stuff from Stack Overflow so that I can look it up again when I face the same problem.
And then I found [Print Stack Overflow posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254101/7952027) and really liked this [stackprinter answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254140/7952027).
It is much better than Chrome <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> stuff. The web clipper of Evernote does not provide good output. For example see [Evernote version](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s648/sh/f8c21545-596c-424f-8ffc-ee09032f4a08/9faf54c10e3bbb0dd1d6dd1ba31e0d94),  and [actual page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3393/command-line-tool-for-extracting-searching-and-converting)

Comment: why not use https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295508/download-stack-overflow-database and make cutom selects

Comment: What happens when you use web clipper on normal Stack Overflow? I mean, it's not Stack Overflow's job to work with every possible note-taking bookmark-keeping application that exists in the world...